# Templated Map/Dictionary Implementation

Tags: c++, templates, dictionary, containers

This is somewhat similar to a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38702816/templated-fixed-variable-sized-class) of mine, I'm trying to implement a templated Map class.

```
template<typename T, size_t M> class Array { ... } // Fixed-size container
template<typename T> class Vector { ... } // Variable-size container
```

**Method 1:**

```
template<typename KeyContainer, typename ValueContainer> class Map
{
    KeyContainer keys;
    ValueContainer values;
}
```

The problem here is I cannot guarantee that both containers will be the same, the user may pass an `Array<T, M>` as the key container and a `Vector<T>` as the value container leading to problems once the Map starts to exceed the size specified in the `Array<T, M>` template.

**Method 2:**

```
template<typename KeyType, typename ValueType, template<typename> class Container> class Map
{
    Container<KeyType> keys;
    Container<ValueType> values;
    // What if Container is an Array<T, M>?
}
```

but as demonstrated in my previous question that I linked it seems it is impossible to do so: receive a container template that has varying parameter count, unless there's some clever template tricks I'm not aware of.

**Method 3:**

Implement *Method 1* and just put a note in the documentation that tells the user that `KeyContainer` and `ValueContainer` must be the same type of container.

**Question:**
What would be the most optimal way to go about this problem?

Comment: Why are you specifying a container for the `Map`?  If you want to duplicate the functionality of `std::map` you need to implement a RB-Tree.

Comment: What do you mean by optimal? What are the constraints? Whats the goal?

Comment: @NathanOliver Forgot to mention that I'm doing this as exercise that's why I didn't mention the STL containers. As for the question of specifying a container for the `Map`, I wanted the class to be flexible enough to be able to accept any type of container implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 2** is a good solution, as you users can always "bind" *template parameters* by using *template aliases*:

```
template <typename T>
using ArrayOf5 = Array<T, 5>;

int main()
{
    Map<int, float, ArrayOf5> m;
}
```

[**live wandbox example**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/52yquQ5b3Amqv1lH)

---

You could allow `Container` to take more *template parameters* by using a *variadic pack*:

```
template <typename...> class Container
```

But then it wouldn't work for *non-type template parameters* as in the case of `Array`.

Comment: That's pretty neat, I've never thought of using `using` that way. +1

Answer (score 1):

You could store data as:

```
template <class Key, class Value, template<typename> class Container>
class Map
{
    Container<std::pair<Key, Value> > store;
};
```

Disclaimer: Personally I don't think this makes much sense. I don't see a use case for changing the `Container` used in a `Map` ever. It is also very hard for any user of your `Map` to see all requirement for a `Container` (eg. what methods does a `Container` need? Which may throw? Which are `const`?) In any reasonable scenario, users will use some default `Container` of yours. In any case the additional template argument won't see much use which is why I'd stick to a specific `Container` type.

Comment: I was just trying out how far I can get away with templates as an exercise, but after reading your answer it does seem that the `Container` template parameters were unnecessary. +1